# Reverse engineering Microsoft Teams web invisible incoming messages

Tags: networking, tracing

I'm currently looking to inspect the network traffic in Chrome when I receieve incoming messages in microsoft teams, but i can't point out where or how is Teams getting the messages from.

When I load new messages or receive live ones ***nothing happens*** on the network tab. And no Websocket has traffic.

I have tried:

- Searching all requests for strings i send in the messages
- Inspecting websockets communication
- inspecting webworkers

To no avail. I do see outgoing messages sent nicely in POST requests. But I can't see the incoming ones for some weird reason. I'll appreciate any help with this, since I'm trying to develop a chrome extension for added Teams functionality.

Outgoing messsage:

[image]

But somehow, teams is not showing incoming traffic in any of the Network tabs or the service worker traffic log, or any websocket either. Why could this be?

Comment: 1) have you tried reloading the page while keeping the "network" tab in chrome open? I have faced many websocket that start before you open dev tool and they will not show up. 2) If 1 not works, then use some tool like Fiddler or Wireshark